# Could not create instance of type: Sitecore.Data.Database error while Installing a Sitecore module on CD server

Tags: installation, content-delivery, module, url-rewrite

I imagined this would be fairly simple given the lack in posts about it (anywhere really) but we're hitting a bit of a problem with this one.

The module in question is `URL Rewrite`.
It's installed fine on the CM server and it all works there. Getting it onto the CD server on the other hand is proving difficult. I've published the content to the web-live database.

I've manually copied all the files from the install package into the appropriate places on the CD server but it brings the entire site down giving the error:

```
Could not create instance of type: Sitecore.Data.Database. No matching constructor was found.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: Sitecore.Exceptions.ConfigurationException: Could not create instance of type: Sitecore.Data.Database. No matching constructor was found.
```

Source Error:

```
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
```

Stack Trace:

```
[ConfigurationException: Could not create instance of type: Sitecore.Data.Database. No matching constructor was found.]
   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +269
   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +128
   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +575
   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase(String name, Boolean assert) +144
   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase(String name) +42
   Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabases() +98
   Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemManager.InitializeEventHandlers() +34
   Sitecore.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeManagers.Process(PipelineArgs args) +41
   (Object , Object[] ) +71
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +328
   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Application_Start() +204
   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Init(HttpApplication app) +642
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +583
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +169
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +396
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +333

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not create instance of type: Sitecore.Data.Database. No matching constructor was found.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +525
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +124
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +700
```

Were running on `Sitecore 8.0`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you copy your Sitecore.Kernel.dll from CM and place it on CD. Also, make sure that the package being used support sitecore 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going through all the files in the package and checking the content of them I found the culprit. There was a file (Hi.UrlRewrite.Prefetch.Master.config) which references the master database which obviously doesn't exist on the CD server. Removing this file stopped the site dying and the redirects now work.